Problem with passing a function (or procedure) as argument for another function
I've a simple fortran script that finds roots of a function in an interval [a,b] using the function "zbrent". This is a simple example looking for roots for y=x^2 - 2 between [0,2].
program test_zbrent

implicit none
integer, parameter :: kr = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
real(kr) :: zero,tol,zbrent

tol  = 1.0e-6_kr ! tolerance
zero = zbrent(fun,0.0_kr,2.0_kr,tol) ! calling zbrent to find the root in [0,2]
print*, zero

contains
real(kr) function fun(x) result(y)
implicit none
integer, parameter :: kr = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
real(kr), intent(in) :: x

y = x**2 - 2.0

end function fun

end program test_zbrent

include "zbrent.f90"

This works fine, but what about if I want to a more general function like y = x**2 + c? where "c" is a parameter? I made some changes but doesn't help
real(kr) function fun(x,c) result(y)
real(kr), intent(in) :: x,c
y = x**2 - c

I got this error when call zbrent: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure 'func' at (1): 'fun' has the wrong number of arguments. Someone can help me with this please? How should I modify the script?. The idea is not to change/modify zbrent.

We have several (more than just the two  now linked, follow the links found in them under Linked and Related as well) questions for problems like this. Check the techniques offered by their answers. Normally, you make a wrapper of some sort. c than is a controlled by a variable in the calling code stored there or in some module.
